# SailsJs - Override Controller Default Methods

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sails.js, overriding

I'm new to SailsJs and I want to perform an override over a default method generated scaffolding, for example:

> Create

So the idea is to do someStuff() before the default the call to create. Basically, is add some functionality before the default create that comes out after the scaffolding, but then I want to still call that functionality to avoid write the code again.

Here is the command that I run.

```
  sails generate api user
```

Here is my controller code:

```
 /**
 * UserController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side logic for managing users
 * @help        :: See http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Controllers
 */

module.exports = {
  create: function (req, res) {
    someStuff();
    call_to_default_create()<--- What to know if posible?
  },        
};
```

Here is the model code:

```
/**
 * User.js
 *
 * @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models
 */

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      minLength: 2
    },
    last_name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      minLength: 2
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      email: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    encrypted_password: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
}
```

I think that the way that works Sails is not inheritance but can I somehow emulate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.create(req, res);`. So your custom `create` method would be:

```
/**
 * UserController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side logic for managing users
 * @help        :: See http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Controllers
 */

module.exports = {
  create: function (req, res) {
    someStuff();
    return sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.create(req, res);
  },        
};
```

I can't find blueprint overriding like this actually documented anywhere, though, so use at your own risk. =)

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to execute code before *create* method : [Lifecycle callbacks](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks).

You can execute your method before or after *create* method, directly in your model.

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            minLength: 2
        },
        last_name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            minLength: 2
        },
        password: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            minLength: 10,
        },
    },

    beforeCreate: (valuesToSet, proceed) => {
        sails.helpers.passwords.hashPassword(valuesToSet.password).exec((err, hashedPassword) => {
            if (err) { return proceed(err); }
            valuesToSet.password = hashedPassword;
            return proceed();
        });
    }
}
```